# Loop with indexed function not defined for some index values

Tags: procedural-programming, indexed-variable

If anyone cares, this is supposed to be a very simple implementation of a Metropolis algorithm for a uniform distribution. I want to plot the variance of the sampled values as a function of an acceptance ratio, *a*. 
The loop in question:

```
    a = 0.1;
    u[0] = RandomReal[];
    While[a < 2.1,
     k = 1;
     While[k < 11,
      u[k] = RandomReal[];
      ut = u[k] - u[k - 1];
      r = Exp[-a*ut];
      If[r > RandomReal[], k = k + 1, k = k]];
     ui = Table[u[k], {k, 10}];
     m[a] = Sum[u[k], {k, 1, 10}]/10;
     v[a] = Variance[ui];
     a = a + 0.1]
```

This is working for the most part, however v[*a*] is undefined for *a*=0.7, 0.9, and *a*>1.5. The weird part is that if I check v[0.7] manually it returns a value, but if I make a table with v[*a*],{*a*,0.1,2,0.1} it shows as undefined at *a*=0.7. I want to know why I'm having trouble for these *a* values.

Answer (score 3):

It is a really bad idea to use floating point numbers for indexing.

In order to see why, have a look at the output of following code after having run your code:

```
DownValues[v][[16]] // FullForm
```

> HoldPattern[v[1.6000000000000003]] :> 0.10194258571474865

As you can see, it is not `v[1.6]` which is defined but `v[1.6000000000000003]`. The deviation of `1.6000000000000003` from `1.6` stems from the fact that you executed `a = a + 0.1` repeatedly. Since floating point numbers are stored in binary format, the number `0.1` cannot be expressed exactly, so the tiny error that *has* to be made may accumulate over time. If the relative error between a number `x` and each number `y` for which `v` has a downvalue is too large, *Mathematica* won't recognize `v[x]` as already defined and thus leaves it unevaluated.

So a more robust way is to use integers for indexing:

```
ClearAll[v];
a = 1;
u[0] = RandomReal[];
While[a < 21, k = 1;
 While[k < 11, u[k] = RandomReal[];
  ut = u[k] - u[k - 1];
  r = Exp[-0.1 a*ut];
  If[r > RandomReal[], k = k + 1, k = k]];
 ui = Table[u[k], {k, 10}];
 m[a] = Sum[u[k], {k, 1, 10}]/10;
 v[a] = Variance[ui];
 a = a + 1
 ]
```

Comment: This was the issue, and an easy fix. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Btw.: It may also be a good idea performancewise to define `v`, `u`, `m`  as a lists of fixed length (if this length is known before the loop start) and to write into the list with `v[[a]] = ...` etc.

Comment: `It is a really bad idea to use floating point numbers for indexing` Yes. Actually in Ada (a very well designed  and safe language), this will generate a compile error.  May be the new Mathematica Lint tool that I saw few days ago in some post can catch such user error, I do not know.